# Passing variables from parameterized Jenkins project using Jenkinsfile, Maven, and Java

Tags: java, macos, maven, jenkins

I have a parameterized Pipeline Jenkins project connected to a Maven project that I forked from https://github.com/jenkins-docs/simple-java-maven-app. I am trying to pass a parameter called "Platform" I have set in the Jenkins Project:
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYF9h.png)

Before implementing this on my own, larger project, I wanted to see if it was possible to pass a parameter from Jenkins to the Java application via Maven. I've tried some solutions seen in below code.

However, no matter what I try, I still get null when running `System.getProperty("platform")`. I'm not sure what I could be doing incorrectly. Am I missing something or is there some incorrect syntax I'm just not identifying?

Code snippets below:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh "mvn -Dplatform=${params.Platform} -B clean package" 
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**deliver.sh**
I added echo "${env.platform}" to see what it returned and I get an error -  *./jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh: line 2: ${env.platform}: bad substitution*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "${env.platform}"
set -x
mvn jar:jar install:install help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.name
set +x

echo 'The following complex command extracts the value of the <name/> element'
echo 'within <project/> of your Java/Maven project''s "pom.xml" file.'
set -x
NAME=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.name | grep "^[^\[]"`
set +x

echo 'The following complex command behaves similarly to the previous one but'
echo 'extracts the value of the <version/> element within <project/> instead.'
set -x
VERSION=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep "^[^\[]"`
set +x

echo 'The following command runs and outputs the execution of your Java'
echo 'application (which Jenkins built using Maven) to the Jenkins UI.'
set -x
java -jar target/${NAME}-${VERSION}.jar
```

**Java main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = System.getProperty("platform");
        System.out.println(test);
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

UPDATE - solution found:
Followed Илиян Михайлов's solution and it worked! Also, in the Java class, instead of using `System.getProperty("platform")` I had to use `System.getenv("Platform")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to set a parameter in the wrong place (in the build step). In maven, each run is independently and not store any information about the parameters. The parameter must be sent when is needed may be on this line mvn jar:jar install:install help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.name -Dplatform="$1" -> this should be sent as parameter from the Jenkins job sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh ${params.Platform}'}